# Posting uniqid generated name into database after file upload. Issue with different variable names

Tags: php

I created a profile form where users can also upload profile pictures. I am using this change the name of the file and upload it:

```
<?php  

/*image upload part*/
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$target_dir = "subsites/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// changing file name to unique name
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$newfilename = uniqid('profilepic_').'.'.end($temp);
$target = "subsites/uploads/" .$newfilename;

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target)) 
        {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $fileuploadcheck = 1;
   } 
        else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        $fileuploadcheck = 0;
   }
}
}
/*image upload part end*/
      ?>
```

And then I want to insert $target to hidden field in form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="FormPicName" id="FormFileName" value=
    <?php
     if ($fileuploadcheck = 1)
    {
     echo $target;
    }
    else
    { NULL; }
     ?>
     >
```

The problem is that the $target value is already different! So I end up with different filename and different value in Database.

How can I overcome this problem?

(edit: i have removed security checking options from file upload part)

Comment: `if ($fileuploadcheck = 1)` missing second = for comparison.

Comment: thank you VolkerK! good eye! :)

Comment: Can be avoided by placing the non-lvalue (i.e. something you cannot assign a value to [simplified]) on the left side like `if ( 1==$fileuploadcheck )` -> syntax error if you forget the second = ;-)